# How do you show the complex Fourier series for $ f(x) = x, \lvert x \rvert , \le 2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

Show that the complex Fourier Series for $$f(x)=x , \lvert x \rvert \le2$$defined over one period, is given by

$$f(x) = \frac{j2}{\pi}\sum_{r=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r}{r} \exp\left(j\frac{r \pi x}{2}\right)$$

I know that it amonts in solving an integral, but it did not coincide with the series. Solving this integral.

$$ c_n=\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^2 te^{-(jn\pi t)/2} dt $$
Integrating by parts yielded into

$$c_n= \frac{1}{(n\pi)^2}(e^{-jn\pi}-1 ) -\frac{1}{jn\pi}(e^{-jn\pi})$$

However,
$$e^{-jn\pi}=\cos(n\pi)-j\sin(n\pi) $$
For the "sin" term it's always zero because its multiple of $\pi$. So it can be boiled down into
$$e^{-jn\pi}=(-1)^n$$
Where $c_n$ may differ depeding on whether n is even or odd.
Now the problem is that it does not coincide with the series.Can anyone tell where is the mistake? 
Remark: j is equivalent to the imgainary number i.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? This amounts to solving an integral.

Comment: I solved the integral but it does not coincide with the series. So I need help in solving the integral.

Comment: Then please include your work solving the integral so we might be able to spot your mistake.

Comment: Great! Go ahead and edit your question to include what you have tried. That way we can pin point where something went wrong.

Comment: Perhaps what you are missing is that the coefficients you get will contain the expression $e^{i\pi r}$, and you failed to notice that $e^{i\pi r}-=(-1)^r$.

Comment: Or perhaps you didn't notice that $\frac{1}{-j}=j$...

Comment: I noticed it, but still struggling with matching up with the series.

Comment: Why are you integrating $\int_0^2$ rather than $\int_{-2}^2$?

Comment: And  how did you get $\frac{1}{(n\pi)^2}$ after integrating by parts? There shouldn't be a square there...

Answer (score 1):

You should have:

$$c_n=\frac{1}{4} \int_{-2}^2 te^{-(jn\pi t)/2} dt$$

Note the $-2$ lower bound. That is probably the main source of your error. For example, that is how you ended up with $\frac{1}{(n\pi)^2}$.

When $n=0$, we easily see that $c_0=\int_{-2}^{2} t\,dt = 0$.

Then, when $n\neq 0$, we integrate by parts, letting $u=t,dv=e^{-jn\pi t/2}\,dt$ then $du=dt$ and $v=\frac{2}{-jn\pi} e^{-jn\pi t/2}=\frac{2j}{n\pi}e^{-jn\pi t/2},$ since $\frac{1}{-j}=j$.

But:

$$\int_{-2}^{2} v\,du = \frac{2j}{n\pi}\int_{-2}^2 e^{-j\pi n/2} = 0$$

when $n\neq 0$.

So we are left with:

$$c_n = \frac{1}{4}\left(u(2)v(2)-u(-2)v(-2)\right)$$

But $u(2)=2, u(-2)=-2$ and you get:

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2}(v(2)+v(-2)) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2j}{n\pi}\left(e^{-jn\pi}+e^{jn\pi}\right)$$

But $e^{jn\pi}=e^{-jn\pi}=(-1)^n$. So:

$$c_n = \frac{2j}{n\pi}(-1)^n$$

Comment: Thnak you so much Thomas